# Excel - how to display "0", "+" or "-"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried googling for some time now, but I have not yet found the answer.

If I have an number (positive, negative, or equal to zero) in, let's say bracket A1, and I wish bracket A2 to show "+" if A1 is positive, "-" if A1 is negative or "0" if A1 is zero, does anyone know how to code this in excel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell A2 enter this formula:

```
=A1
```

Apply the following number formatting to cell A2: `+;-;0`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're asking is a duplicate of the question asked here:
https://superuser.com/questions/612434/how-can-i-escape-special-characters-in-cell-formatting-in-excel

So to repeat the answer, simply put a backslash ( \ ) in front of whatever character would otherwise have a special function.

Comment: My question has little to do with the question you linked to.